# Success Alert popup in mvc4 View without using jquery and AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, razor

Is it possible to get an alert popup on return to same view after success in mvc4 without using ajax begin form?

I'm trying to submit a form and on success want to show a alert box without using ajax and jquery .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you submit form, I think then you are redirecting, am i right? So you can use `TempData` for this purpose:

In controller action:

```
if(success)
{
    TempData["AlertMessage"] = "my alert message";
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
}
```

The view which `SomeAction` action returns (or in layout view):

```
@{
    var message = TempData["AlertMessage"] ?? string.Empty;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if(message)
        alert(message);
</script>
```

**NOTE**: If you are not redirecting, but returning view, just use `ViewBag` instead of `TempData`.

Comment: no.. i am not redirecting . Thats exactly why i want the user to see the alert popup window :)

Comment: If you are returning view, then just use `ViewBag` instead of `TempData` ))

Comment: It Worked !! :) Could you edit your answer with the same so i can mark it as answer ? :)